# QThreadPoolServer is not responding

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, tcp

I wrote a simple threadpool server with qt. When i try to connect to server on win 32/64 all works good. But when I use linux centos 7 server is not responding. I use 127.0.0.1:8080 for server address. Also server uses database mysql. When I try to connect via telnet it connects but nothing happens. I checked for open ports with netstat. Maybe I missed something because of this the server is not working?

Here is my code for server. In fact, there is also an http request handler, but it does not reach it, I tried to output a string in the constructor - it is not called.

#### QthreadPoolServer.cpp

```
#include "QThreadPoolServer.h"
#include "QSocketRunnable.h"
#include "ConfigReader.h"
#include <memory>

QThreadPoolServer::QThreadPoolServer()
{
    ConfigReader reader(config_file_path);

    QHostAddress server_IP(reader.getServerAddress());
    int port = reader.getServerPort();

    listen(QHostAddress::localhost, 8080); 
    std:: cout << serverError() << errorString().toStdString();
    m_threadPool = std::make_shared<QThreadPool>(this);
}

void QThreadPoolServer::incomingConnection(int handle)
{
    std::shared_ptr<QSocketRunnable> runnable = std::make_shared<QSocketRunnable>(handle);
    runnable->setAutoDelete(false);
    m_threadPool->start(runnable.get());
}

QThreadPoolServer::~QThreadPoolServer()
{
    m_threadPool->~QThreadPool();
}
```

#### QThreadPoolServer.h

```
#ifndef QTHREADPOOLSERVER_H
#define QTHREADPOOLSERVER_H

#include <QTcpServer>
#include <QThreadPool>
#include <memory>

class QThreadPoolServer : public QTcpServer
{
public:
    explicit QThreadPoolServer();

    void incomingConnection(int handle);

    ~QThreadPoolServer();
private:
    std::shared_ptr<QThreadPool> m_threadPool;
};

#endif // QTHREADPOOLSERVER_H
```

#### QSocketRunnable.cpp

```
#include "QSocketRunnable.h"
#include <QString>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>


QSocketRunnable::QSocketRunnable(int handle) : m_descriptor(handle) { }

void QSocketRunnable::run()
{
    QTcpSocket* socket = new QTcpSocket();
    socket->setSocketDescriptor(m_descriptor);
    socket->waitForReadyRead();
    QString request_data = QString(socket->readAll());

    HttpRequestHandler handler(request_data);
    handler.makeResponse();

    QString http_response_result = handler.getHttpResponse();
    std::cout << http_response_result.toStdString() << "\n";
    socket->write(http_response_result.toUtf8());
    socket->waitForBytesWritten(90000);

    socket->disconnectFromHost();
    socket->close();
    socket->deleteLater();
}
```

#### QSocketRunnable.h

```
#ifndef QSOCKETRUNNABLE_H
#define QSOCKETRUNNABLE_H

#include <QRunnable>
#include <QTcpSocket>
#include <QtDebug>
#include <QString>

//#include "IDHelper.h"
//#include "JsonFormatter.h"
//#include "HttpRequestHandler.h"

class QSocketRunnable : public QRunnable
{
public:
    QSocketRunnable(int handle);
    void run() override;
private:
    int m_descriptor;
};

#endif // QSOCKETRUNNABLE_H
```

#### main.cpp

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include "QThreadPoolServer.h"
#include "signal.h"
#include <sstream>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QThreadPoolServer server;

    return a.exec();
}
```

Also `std:: cout << serverError() << errorString().toStdString();` returns "-1" that means `QAbstractSocket::UnknownSocketError -1  An unidentified error occurred.`

Comment: You're reading ServerIP and port from your config but not using them -- instead you're explicitly using  QHostAddress::localhost and 8080.
Just a vague suggestion, but possibly "localhost" is an IPV6 address in your linux environment. Try "0.0.0.0" in place of localhost in your listen call (note that means listening on external network too, which you might not want, but it's a test)

Comment: @AndrewMcGuinness I know it, my config file has ip 127.0.0.1 port 8080 and behavior with these parameters is the same

Comment: @AndrewMcGuinness With "0.0.0.0" the same behavior

Comment: `void incomingConnection(int handle);` - how is this called? Please look at the [documentation for Qt6](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtcpserver.html#incomingConnection) or [Qt5](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcpserver.html#incomingConnection) to fix the function signature and use the '[override](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override)' keyword to get compiler errors when trying to overwrite a virtual function.

Comment: @chehrlic Ok, I use `void incomingConnection(qintptr socketDescriptor) override` and I got pure virtual call error. How can I fix this? Why it works on windows without 'override' and with my function signature?

Comment: When your program crashes you normally use a debugger, look where and why it crashes and then fix it. How should we now where and why it crashes?

Comment: @chehrlic Thanks for your reply. I found several server implementations via qthreadpool and all override `void incomingConnection(int handle)`. It works well on win but not firing on linux. When i write like `virtual void incomingConnection(int handle) override` of course it crashes. So how do I override this method so that it runs when connected?

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-threadedfortuneserver-example.html

Comment: I found a mistake, it`s with my raw RAII implementation:)

Comment: If you find an example which overrides incomingConnection() which takes an integer than it's an old, outdated version for Qt4. It can not work with Qt5 or Qt6 because, as already said, there is no such a function which you can override in any way so your function will not be called.

Comment: @chehrlic Yeah, you right. This also affected the performance, it turns out that I did not override the method with such a signature. So it didn't fired. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. As @chehrlic correctly noted: I had an incorrectly overloaded function, so here is the ritht version of QThreadPoolServer.h

#### QThreadPoolServer.h

```
#ifndef QTHREADPOOLSERVER_H
#define QTHREADPOOLSERVER_H

#include <QTcpServer>
#include <QThreadPool>
#include <memory>

class QThreadPoolServer : public QTcpServer
{
public:
    explicit QThreadPoolServer();
protected:
    void incomingConnection(qintptr handle) override;

    ~QThreadPoolServer();
private:
    std::shared_ptr<QThreadPool> m_threadPool;
};

#endif // QTHREADPOOLSERVER_H
```

2. My my implementation did not work correctly with a smart pointer to a runnable object:

#### QThreadPoolServer.cpp

```
void QThreadPoolServer::incomingConnection(qintptr handle)
{
    QSocketRunnable* runnable = new QSocketRunnable(handle)
    runnable->setAutoDelete(true);
    m_threadPool->start(runnable);
}
```